# How remove extension inside url by rewrite

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

How i can remove the extension `.php` from url like that:

```
https://example.com/file.php/a/b/b
```

When the file is on the end of url i use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php/?$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

But the file is in the midle, how can i do that?

Comment: Replace `/?$` with `\b` in your regex

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to use is a word boundary, which is:

```
\b
```

https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\b $1 [R=301,L]
```

A short summary is a word boundary is a zero-width non letter/number.  Pretty much in your case the slash or the end of line.  That sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

with this ruler select all **.php** in the web address

```
RewriteRule \S[php]\S(?=\/) $1 [R=301,L]
```

https://regex101.com/

Comment: tks for atention,dont take the dot